# Multiple Angles in Plane Geometry

Tags: geometry, angle

My question is regarding the geometric understanding of things such as $\sin (A+B+C+D)$ where one moves out of the typical 'trigonometry' setting because this is dealing with more than $3$ angles. I cannot grasp what this would look like if we were dealing with this in classic Euclidean geometry. So what exactly is the sine of the sum of multiple angles, geometrically speaking? What does it look like? Can this be studied further or has it been already? Does this have reverberations deeper in mathematics that can be exploited to ease other problems?

A bit of a sidenote: I have written out several expansions of these formulas so I do not need the general expansion formulas for this sort of stuff.

Comment: I don't understand your question. the sum of angles is a new angle and the sine of this new angle is the sine of the sum.The sine of the sum of the three angles of a triangle is not very interesting because the sum is always 180 degrees and its sine is 0

Answer (score 2):

As a concrete example, here’s a visual explanation of where the double angle formula for sine comes from:

[image: unit circle]

If $A$ and $B$ are angles, then $A+B$ is **how much plane angle is encompassed by the both of them**—for example, if they’re adjacent. **You’re right to be confused by adding two angles**, as you can’t really *add* things that aren’t numbers. That’s why geometers write $m\angle A$ to indicate the *number* associated with the angle as opposed to the angle itself. So, **really we should say that $A$ and $B$ are the *measures* of two plane angles**.

To familiarize yourself with this concept, you could look at altitudes of triangles or divide an isosceles triangle into two right triangles. In both of these instances, one of the corners of the triangle has a third segment intersecting it, dividing that corner into ‘two’ angles.

Below is another example that I just drew up. It shows how you might interpret the corner of a triangle as one angle or as the sum of the measures of two angles.

[image: triangle]

If you’re a geometry student, you’ve probably seen some variation of this problem. You would have been given $x$ and $y$ as well as any two of $α$, $β$, $γ$, $δ$ and $\varepsilon$ to solve for $z$, which you could do by using the definition of sine or the law of cosines.

Comment: Hopefully I haven’t rambled so long that I’ve confused you anew!

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Of course I can add angles. This is done by juxtaposition. And a deeper analysis shows that angles can be  interpreted as numbers: the number is the corresponding part of the circumference of the unit circle. Besides that, there are vectors in the plane that are actually no numbers but we can define an addition for vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of angles is a new angle and the sine of this new angle is the sine of the sum  which we can get by juxtaposition of the four angles. The sine of the sum of the three angles of a triangle is not very interesting because the sum is always $180^\circ$  and its sine is $0$. 
[image]